# C Linked List pointer understanding

Tags: c, list, pointers, data-structures

I'm trying to understand how C linked list pointer works.
I understand that a pointer to a variable is a "link" to an address memory, and that a pointer to a pointer is, sometimes, a reference to a pointer itself.

What concerns me is how could, for example, a node reference modify the original list value, but not the list itself.

I'll explain myself better:

```
void insertNode(struct node** head, int value) {

    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    struct node* ref = (*head); //this is a reference. -> same address.

    //base case 
    if((*head) == NULL) {
        //do things
    } else { // not null
        while(ref->next != null) {
            ref = ref->next; //THIS: how can this not modify the head itself?
        }

        //null spot found, set up node
        new->value = 10; //some int here
        new->next = NULL;

        ref->next = new; //Instead, how can this modify the head? and why?
    }
}
```

here's a little snippets of code, and my question is:
Yes, i'm holding a reference to head through **ref**.
But why

```
ref = ref->next;
```

only modify ref itself, while

```
ref->next = new
```

modify also the head?

through GDB i saw that both, at the beginning, share the same address memory, but ref only modify the referenced list on the new insert.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some pictures will help.

Before calling `insertNode`, you have a sequence of nodes linked like so:

```
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

You have a pointer (call it `h`) that points to the first element of the list:

```
+---+
| h |
+---+
  |
  V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

When you call `insertNode`, you pass *a pointer to* `h` in as a parameter, which we call `head`:

```
+------+
| head |
+------+
  |
  V
+---+
| h |
+---+
  |
  V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

You create a pointer variable named `ref` that takes the value of `*head` (`h`); IOW, `ref` winds up pointing to the first element of the list:

```
+------+ +-----+
| head | | ref |
+------+ +-----+
  |        |       
  V        |
+---+      |
| h |      |
+---+      |
  |   +----+
  V   V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

Then you create another node on the heap, and assign that pointer to a local variable named `new`:

```
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
| head | | ref | | new | ---> | value | next |
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
  |        |       
  V        |       
+---+      |       
| h |      |    
+---+      |     
  |   +----+     
  V   V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

So, the thing to notice is that while `ref` and `*head` (`h`) have the same *value* (the address of the first node in the list), they are different objects.  Thus, anything that changes the value of `ref` does not affect either `head` or `h`.

So, if we execute this loop

```
while(ref->next != null) {
    ref = ref->next;
```

the result of the first iteration is

```
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
| head | | ref | | new | ---> | value | next |
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
  |        |       
  V        |       
+---+      |       
| h |      |    
+---+      |     
  |        +------------+     
  V                     V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

After another iteration we get

```
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
| head | | ref | | new | ---> | value | next |
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
  |        |       
  V        |       
+---+      |       
| h |      |    
+---+      |     
  |        +----------------------------------+     
  V                                           V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

At this point, `ref->next` is `NULL`, so the loop exits.

We then assign values to `new->value` and `new->next`, such that `new->next` is `NULL`:

```
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
| head | | ref | | new | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
  |        |       
  V        |       
+---+      |       
| h |      |    
+---+      |     
  |        +----------------------------------+     
  V                                           V
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+      
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

Finally, we set `ref->next` to the value of `new`, thus adding the node `new` points to to the end of the list:

```
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+
| head | | ref | | new | ---> | value | next | ---|||
+------+ +-----+ +-----+      +-------+------+               
  |        |                    ^                                
  V        |                    |                               
+---+      |                    +-------------------------------+
| h |      |                                                    |
+---+      |                                                    |
  |        +----------------------------------+                 |
  V                                           V                 |
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+    |  
| value | next | ---> | value | next | ---> | value | next | ---+
+-------+------+      +-------+------+      +-------+------+
```

Note that `ref->next` isn't pointing to the *variable* `new`, it's pointing to the thing that `new` points to.

So, that's why updating `ref` does not affect `head` (or `*head` (`h`)).  The base case, where the list is empty, *will* end up writing to `*head` (`h`), setting it to point to a new node allocated from the heap.

Comment: That definitely helped me understand in a clear and easy way all the pointer backscene into the list. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`ref` is just a pointer; modifying `ref` will not modify what is *pointed* by `ref`.

The `while` loop is actually just looking for the last element of the list. After the `while` loop , `ref` will simply point to the last element of the list.

**First "mystery" line:**

```
ref = ref->next; //THIS: how can this not modify the head itself?
```

Here we just read `ref->next`, so the head cannot be modified.

**Second "mystery" line:**

```
ref->next = new; //Instead, how can this modify the head? and why?
```

Here we modify what is pointed by `ref`. At this line `ref` points either to the last element of the list, or it points the head (which is also the last element of the list if there is only one element in the list, or which is the newly created head (to be done in `//do things`) if the list was empty.